# IIS 7 - Static Content Attempting Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have a WebForms application hosted in IIS 7. When I run the site from Visual Studio 2010, my static content all loads perfectly. We have the same site hosted in another production environment and the site works great there also.

However, when I am trying to host the site in a new production environment, it is giving me a status code of 302 Found whenever it attempts to load the static content.

When I open up Chrome's Developer Console and look at the network, it shows this:

```
/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fjs%2fjquery.js
```

This leads me to believe that something in IIS7 is forcing authentication to occur on static content. Is there anything I should check to see what the likely cause of this problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, for whatever reason, I had to add the IUSR user and give it access to Read on my web apps. I am not sure what changed that made this a requirement. If anyone knows, please feel free to add comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the same permissions as for wwwroot folder the problem disappears:

Users and IIS_IUSRS - read access